# Taking average of pretrained embeddings in model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 300, weights=[embedding_vectors], input_length=max_len, trainable=False)(input)
**average_layer = Average()(embedding_layer)**
dense_layer_1 = Dense(no_units,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers(1e-5))(average_layer)
dropout_layer_1 = Dropout(0.3)(dense_layer_1)
dense_layer_2 = Dense(no_units,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers(1e-5))(dropout_layer_1)
dropout_layer_2 = Dropout(0.3)(dnese_layer_2)
output = Dense(no_classes,activation='softmax')(droupout_layer_2)

DAN = Model(inputs=input,outputs=output)
DAN.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

Created code for developing DAN for sentiment analysis. But while taking average of pretrained embedding I am getting error as average layer works on lists and I have matrix of size (vocab_size,embedding_dim). I want to calculate column wise average. Which layer I should use?

Comment: [you can have a look at creating a custom layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers)

Comment: While using functional API in keras, how to pass  embedding matrix for customized layer? Previous layer is embedding layer with weights as embedding matrix.

Comment: It seems u are looking for GlobalAveragePooling1d